# STRAVA – OAUTH2 of laravel, error

Tags: laravel-5

After using STRAVA – OAUTH2 of laravel, I am getting following error. Could anyone help me on this
ErrorException in StravaController.php line 27:
Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1\StravaController::$app

This error occured when provided this line of code inside the function and before the Socialite method

```
$key = 'SocialiteProviders.config.strava';
$config = new \SocialiteProviders\Manager\Config('key', 'secret', 'callbackUri');
$this->app->instance($key, $config)
```

Comment: In the above code I have also tried app($key, $config). Still it didn't bring any luck

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an strava library object called **app** with **client id** and **client secret**. Then you can call the instance.